# why authorization content is not available in access token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, keycloak

I am trying to add keycloak as identity server in my Asp.net mVC application by using Owin , keycloak identity model library. I am getting all information in access token except Authorization content . What will be reason for this ? . Below I mentioned what are things I done in keycloak server and ASP.net mvc Application.

**KeyCloak:**

1. I created Realm with Name as HMIS.
2. I created client with Name as Administrator. In this Client I change access type as *confidential*.
3. Then I allowed authorization in same client and I set valid URL for redirect
4. Then I created resource , scope , user based policy and it permission under authorization. ( default policy and permission also there ) .
5. During authorization evaluate in keycloak UI I got below  decode access token.

```
{
  "exp": 1607412284,
  "iat": 1607411984,
  "jti": "9d74f32a-3e2c-4fac-95d7-11feb5566d32",
  "aud": [
    "Administrator",
    "account"
  ],
  "sub": "5cf9079d-3a75-48ca-906a-19e813727ee0",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "Administrator",
  "session_state": "cf1b8e41-a015-4279-8e2a-2796643a4174",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "Administrator": {
      "roles": [
        "User",
        "uma_protection"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "scopes": [
          "NEW",
          "PRINT",
          "EXCEL",
          "EDIT"
        ],
        "rsid": "f7e6cbef-f203-4d71-9806-c7cdec402077",
        "rsname": "Area"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scope": "Audience email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "karthick"
}
```

6. During client scope evaluation in keycloak UI . I am getting below decode access token in which **authorization content** is not available.

```
{
  "exp": 1607412523,
  "iat": 1607412223,
  "jti": "c8a08432-0993-41d6-9786-dac65aeb33b1",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/HMIS",
  "aud": [
    "Administrator",
    "account"
  ],
  "sub": "5cf9079d-3a75-48ca-906a-19e813727ee0",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "Administrator",
  "session_state": "833d6dae-0501-4815-beac-c6373d3b19a6",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "Administrator": {
      "roles": [
        "User",
        "uma_protection"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid Audience email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "karthick"
}
```

**Asp.net MVC**

1. In Asp.net Mvc application I used Owin and keycloak identity mode libraries to get access token from keycloak server ( using client secret key ) and I decode it by using JWT libraries.
2. In received access token also **authorization content** is not available. after decoding Like below I am receiving json format data ( which is same as client scope evaluation json format ).

```
{
  "exp": 1607412523,
  "iat": 1607412223,
  "jti": "c8a08432-0993-41d6-9786-dac65aeb33b1",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/HMIS",
  "aud": [
    "Administrator",
    "account"
  ],
  "sub": "5cf9079d-3a75-48ca-906a-19e813727ee0",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "Administrator",
  "session_state": "833d6dae-0501-4815-beac-c6373d3b19a6",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "Administrator": {
      "roles": [
        "User",
        "uma_protection"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid Audience email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "karthick"
}
```

Below Code I using in asp.net mvc for authenticating.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Name of the persistent authentication middleware for lookup
            const string persistentAuthType = "testKeycloak_cookie_auth";

            // --- Cookie Authentication Middleware - Persists user sessions between requests
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType
            });
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType); // Cookie is primary session store
            
            // --- Keycloak Authentication Middleware - Connects to central Keycloak database
            app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // App-Specific Settings
                ClientId = "Administrator", // *Required* SOLUTION
                ClientSecret = "e6022499-9e91-417f-95de-b9312b67f5b0", // If using public authentication, delete this line SECRET ID SOLUTIONS
                VirtualDirectory = "", // Set this if you use a virtual directory when deploying to IIS
                //Scope="BTNPRINT",
                // Instance-Specific Settings
                Realm = "HMIS", // Don't change this unless told to do so
                KeycloakUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth", // Enter your Keycloak URL here
               
                // Template-Specific Settings
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType, // Sets the above cookie with the Keycloak data
                AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType, // Unique identifier for the auth middleware
                AllowUnsignedTokens = false,
                DisableIssuerSigningKeyValidation = false,
                DisableIssuerValidation = false,
                DisableAudienceValidation = true,
                
                //TokenClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                DisableRefreshTokenSignatureValidation = true,
            });
```

So what will reason for missing of authorization content ?. I knew some where I missed to configure .

Comment: When you normally ask for a token (no in the GUI) do you get the authorization on the token?

Comment: I am not getting authorization in token during getting from asp .NET mvc (already mentioned in question)

Comment: But on step 5 it was there

Comment: In 5 step I am doing evaluate in Keycloak GUI ( client -> authorization -> evaluate ) that time I am getting authorization